# Texture mapping or texture tiling for a voxel-based game? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, voxel

I’m building a voxel-based game that visually resembles Minecraft in many aspects, namely low-resolution textures and square blocks.

Obviously optimization is important for these kinds of games for a whole host of reasons, but there are two that I have come across that seem mutually exclusive: texture mapping and texture tiling.

With texture mapping, I would generate a single texture map of all existing block textures, which I’ve read can greatly improve performance. The issue with this optimization is that texture tiling doesn’t appear to be possible, as that technique relies upon the first and last pixels of a texture file being for the same texture, which is no longer true when mapping is used. This also means that the messes of neighboring blocks can never be combined as far as I am aware.

With tiling, large groups of blocks with identical textures can be combined into a single, 2 tri mesh. While efficient, each texture would need its own Material object, which means each differing block texture would need its own submesh.

Which of these would be more likely to offer superior overall performance?

Comment: Combining meshes sound great but it is very hard to implement.

Comment: Combining textures would be a nice thing to do. Use the hardware instancing to draw multiple meshes. Include a textureindex in the instance data to address the right texture _(re-address the UV by dividing by the tile count)_ . You could even try to generate the cubes with the Geometry Shader.

Answer (score 1):

They seem mutually exclusive, but they aren't realy.
Minecraft doesn't repeat the texture, it repeats the UV's.

**How it works:**
For all rectangles sharing a texture, make sure they have their UV's at the same place.
For example, all grass rectangles should have their UV's on top of the grass texture in the atlas.
To make it looks nice, you would need [seamless textures](https://plusspec.com/seamless-texture-tileable-texture/).
Also to prevent edge bleeding, you would need to make sure that all textures have some [padding](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Edge_padding) in between.

**Example:**
I made a quick blender project showing it.
The sideways rectangles all have the UV at the same texture area, while the top one has it's UV on a different texture area.
The "repeat" is done by using seamless textures in the atlas.
In this case. no padding was added, as it's not needed for pixelated textures.

[image]
Texture is taken from Minecraft.

Comment: Point filtering and no mips should not require padding. If that is acceptable depends on your game though, higher res textures with no mips might look really bad in the distance.

Comment: I mentioned that in the example. However OP did not specify how he filtered, only that it's low res and somewhat like minecraft.

Comment: I think that @QuaternionsRock means, that he's is combining multiple cubes by merging them, This would create the problem that the tiled textures are unable to repeat.

Comment: Why? As long as the UVs dont change, the texture repeats by definition. Texture repeat and clamp only takes effect if an UV is outside the texture space.